# When using the command ECHO in a batch file the ASCII writing after isn't expected?

Tags: batch-file

Here are 3 versions of a script.
I would please just like an explanation and correction.

Version 1 test:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :Echo.Color.Init

goto main

:Echo.Color %1=Color %2=Str [%3=/n]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~2"
:Echo.Color.2
:# Replace path separators in the string, so that the final path still refers to the current path.
set "str=a%ECHO.DEL%!str:\=a%ECHO.DEL%\..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%ECHO.DEL%/..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
:# Go to the script directory and search for the trailing -
pushd "%ECHO.DIR%"
findstr /p /r /a:%~1 "^^-" "!str!\..\!ECHO.FILE!" nul
popd
:# Remove the name of this script from the output. (Dependant on its length.)
for /l %%n in (1,1,12) do if not "!ECHO.FILE:~%%n!"=="" <nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Remove the other unwanted characters "\..\: -"
<nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Append the optional CRLF
if not "%~3"=="" echo.
endlocal & goto :eof

:Echo.Color.Var %1=Color %2=StrVar [%3=/n]
if not defined %~2 goto :eof
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!%~2!"
goto :Echo.Color.2

:Echo.Color.Init
set "ECHO.COLOR=call :Echo.Color"
set "ECHO.DIR=%~dp0"
set "ECHO.FILE=%~nx0"
set "ECHO.FULL=%ECHO.DIR%%ECHO.FILE%"
:# Use prompt to store a backspace into a variable. (Actually backspace+space+backspace)
for /F "tokens=1 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "ECHO.DEL=%%a"
goto :eof

)
:main
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading Files!"
choice /d y /t 7 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loaded!"
choice /d y /t 7 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nulecho    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   
echo   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  
echo   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  
echo   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  
echo _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| 
echo "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' 
echo 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   
echo   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  
echo   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  
echo   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  
echo _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| 
echo "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' 
echo 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loaded!"
choice /d y /t 4 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Starting WinActivate"
choice /d y /t 12 > nul
```

Version 2 test:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :Echo.Color.Init

goto main

:Echo.Color %1=Color %2=Str [%3=/n]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~2"
:Echo.Color.2
:# Replace path separators in the string, so that the final path still refers to the current path.
set "str=a%ECHO.DEL%!str:\=a%ECHO.DEL%\..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%ECHO.DEL%/..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
:# Go to the script directory and search for the trailing -
pushd "%ECHO.DIR%"
findstr /p /r /a:%~1 "^^-" "!str!\..\!ECHO.FILE!" nul
popd
:# Remove the name of this script from the output. (Dependant on its length.)
for /l %%n in (1,1,12) do if not "!ECHO.FILE:~%%n!"=="" <nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Remove the other unwanted characters "\..\: -"
<nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Append the optional CRLF
if not "%~3"=="" echo.
endlocal & goto :eof

:Echo.Color.Var %1=Color %2=StrVar [%3=/n]
if not defined %~2 goto :eof
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!%~2!"
goto :Echo.Color.2

:Echo.Color.Init
set "ECHO.COLOR=call :Echo.Color"
set "ECHO.DIR=%~dp0"
set "ECHO.FILE=%~nx0"
set "ECHO.FULL=%ECHO.DIR%%ECHO.FILE%"
:# Use prompt to store a backspace into a variable. (Actually backspace+space+backspace)
for /F "tokens=1 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "ECHO.DEL=%%a"
goto :eof

)
:main
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading Files!"
choice /d y /t 7 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loaded!"
choice /d y /t 7 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loaded!"
choice /d y /t 4 > nul
cat << "EOF"
'    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
'   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
'   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
'   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
' _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
EOF 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Starting WinActivate"
choice /d y /t 12 > nul
```

Version 3:

```
@echo off
setlocal

call :Echo.Color.Init

goto main

:Echo.Color %1=Color %2=Str [%3=/n]
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=%~2"
:Echo.Color.2
:# Replace path separators in the string, so that the final path still refers to the current path.
set "str=a%ECHO.DEL%!str:\=a%ECHO.DEL%\..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:/=a%ECHO.DEL%/..\%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%!"
set "str=!str:"=\"!"
:# Go to the script directory and search for the trailing -
pushd "%ECHO.DIR%"
findstr /p /r /a:%~1 "^^-" "!str!\..\!ECHO.FILE!" nul
popd
:# Remove the name of this script from the output. (Dependant on its length.)
for /l %%n in (1,1,12) do if not "!ECHO.FILE:~%%n!"=="" <nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Remove the other unwanted characters "\..\: -"
<nul set /p "=%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%%ECHO.DEL%"
:# Append the optional CRLF
if not "%~3"=="" echo.
endlocal & goto :eof

:Echo.Color.Var %1=Color %2=StrVar [%3=/n]
if not defined %~2 goto :eof
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "str=!%~2!"
goto :Echo.Color.2

:Echo.Color.Init
set "ECHO.COLOR=call :Echo.Color"
set "ECHO.DIR=%~dp0"
set "ECHO.FILE=%~nx0"
set "ECHO.FULL=%ECHO.DIR%%ECHO.FILE%"
:# Use prompt to store a backspace into a variable. (Actually backspace+space+backspace)
for /F "tokens=1 delims=#" %%a in ('"prompt #$H# & echo on & for %%b in (1) do rem"') do set "ECHO.DEL=%%a"
goto :eof

)
:main
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading Files!"
choice /d y /t 7 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loaded!"
choice /d y /t 7 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nulecho    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   
echo   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  
echo   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  
echo   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  
echo _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| 
echo "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' 
echo 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   
echo   / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  
echo   \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  
echo   |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  
echo _|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| 
echo "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' 
echo 
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading.."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loading..."
choice /d y /t 2 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Loaded!"
choice /d y /t 4 > nul
echo '   ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
echo '  / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  '
echo '  \__ \   | |__ | |\/| | | (_ |   |   /  '
echo '  |___/   |____||_|__|_|  \___|   |_|_\  '
echo '_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""|_|"""""| '
echo '"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
echo '                             '
call :Echo.Color 1b "DiGITAL (Bar Technology) - WinActivate"
call :Echo.Color a0 "Starting WinActivate"
choice /d y /t 12 > nul
```

I cant figure out what is wrong (I didn't put end at the bottom or anything because I hadn't finished and it would've played through the script anyway because of the timeouts by choice `/d y /t [TIME] > nul`).

I would ***REALLY*** appreciate an answer.
Thanks

Comment: I did try CAT without the quotes

Comment: What is the question exactly?

Comment: To get the script fixed create a BAT file and run it yourself

Comment: Do you want we review 3 long codes to realize what is wrong with they, with _no_ indication from your part of the problem? Sorry, but SO don't work this way. You should post a short code section that show the problem with the actual output and the desired output...

Answer (score 1):

I honestly didn't even look at any code outside of the ascii, but the one thing I saw right off the bat was you're not escaping some of the special characters.
Here's the fixed ascii portion of your code. Echoing multiple pipes `"|"` looks as ugly as my prom date, but looks proper while ran. Hopefully this solves your issue.

```
@echo off
ECHO '    ___     _     __  __    ___     ___   '
ECHO '   / __^|   ^| ^|   ^|  \/  ^|  / __^|   ^| _ \  '
ECHO '   \__ \   ^| ^|__ ^| ^|\/^| ^| ^| (_ ^|   ^|   /  '
ECHO '   ^|___/   ^|____^|^|_^|__^|_^|  \___^|   ^|_^|_\  '
ECHO ' _^|"""""|_|"""""^|_^|"""""|_|"""""^|_^|"""""| '
ECHO ' "`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-'"`-0-0-' '
pause
```

Comment: You may also use `set /P` command to enclose the Ascii string in quotes this way: `set /P "= / __|   | |   |  \/  |  / __|   | _ \  " < nul` followed by an `echo/`

Comment: Great! Just gonna get the colours working on the bottom bar where it says 'Loading...'. Thanks! My project is going to work. This was meant to be a fix for the liscencing error with SLUI. The user would change the permissions then run this program and it automatically sorts everything out (for unexperienced users who are having problems). I better get to work, thanks again!